# using find with exec

Tags: bash, find

I want to copy files found by find (with exec cp option) but, i'd like to change name of those files - e.g `find ... -exec cp '{}' test_path/"test_"'{}'` , which to my test_path should copy all files found by find but with prefix 'test'. but it ain't work.

I'd be glad if anyone could give me some ideas how to do it.

best regards

Comment: AHHAHAH wow i think all of us who answreed this one should get a badge for like "most people with simular answer to same question at the same time"

Comment: and by simular i mostly just mean that we all used a for loop and managed the operation with a temp variable

Comment: -exec isn't what you want to use here.  The purpose of "-exec" is to run a command on each file to determine if it should be included in find's list of results, this is why grep is the most common example for this usage.

Answer (score 1):

if you have Bash 4.0 and assuming you are find txt files

```
cd /path
for file in ./**/*.txt
do
  echo cp "$file" "/test_path/test${file}"
done
```

of with GNU find

```
find /path -type f -iname "*.txt" | while read -r -d"" FILE
do
    cp "$FILE" "test_${FILE}"
done
```

OR another version of GNU find+bash

```
find /path -type f -name "*txt" -printf "cp '%p' '/tmp/test_%f'\n" | bash
```

OR this ugly one if you don't have GNU find

```
$ find /path -name '*.txt' -type f -exec basename {} \; | xargs -I file echo cp /path/file /destination/test_file
```

Comment: any ideas how to use it without enetring the path ?

Comment: @ghostdog74: you forgot the "/test" in the first find version.

Comment: @dennis, thanks. I have edited, but if its wrong again, pls do the edit for me. thks.
@JosiP, what OS are you on? Solaris?

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `find . -name "FILES.EXT"`; do cp $i test_path/test_`basename $i`; done
```

It is assumed that you are in the directory that has the files to be copied and test_path is a subdir of it.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the entire `test_path/"test_"'{}'` in `""`
Like:

`find ... -exec cp "{}" "test_path/test_{}" \;`

Comment: This does not actually work as {} takes the whole find as result so you will get test_path/test_yourfolder/file.txt from /yourfolder/file.txt

Comment: But if {} is a complete path (as it so often is with `find`) will "test_path/test_{}" mean what you want?

Comment: I assumed that OP wanted to copy each file to a test_path dir wherever the file was found.
So i went on that line of thought.

Answer (score 0):

I would break it up a bit, like this;

```
 for line in `find /tmp -type f`; do FULL=$line; name=`echo $line|rev|cut -d / -f -1|rev` ; echo cp $FULL "new/location/test_$name" ;done
```

Here's the output;

```
cp /tmp/gcc.version new/location/test_gcc.version
cp /tmp/gcc.version2 new/location/test_gcc.version2
```

Naturally remove the echo from the last part, so it's not just echo'ng what it woudl of done and running cp

Comment: hoho! but i vote for my simular solution as the most flexiable, does not require current dir and can cp into an arbitrially deep/complex dest folder!! ;)  however ya it may be the slowest, maybe not if you got lotsa core's tho!!